# Protractor/AngularJS Calling a function in a controller to update ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, integration-testing, protractor, end-to-end

I'm having some problems with my test approach for a (complex) project.

Situation is as follows; we have 2 angular apps and multiple API server applications. The first Angular app contains a form which calls a login API. The API can return lots of different statuses. Of all those statuses only one results in an login which is OK. If this is the case a second angular app is called. If this is not the case one of many partials is loaded within the first app.

Currently I have unit tests for the different components (services, controllers etc), e2e tests using protractor to test the behavior of the pages. And finally some integration tests to test functional flows across the multiple front end/back end apps. The API's are fully tested independently.

For the e2e tests of the first Angular app I'm now calling the login API to test every partial page. Because we have quite complex and different build processes for the Angular and API apps I would like to remove the API dependency for the e2e tests and test the interface only in the integration test.

The navigation setup is as follows:

I have a form with a Login Controller and a Navigation Controller. If the form is submitted a login function is called.

pseudocode:

```
$scope.login = function () {
 callAPIService();
 if (result = ok) {
   $scope.redirect($scope.pages.ok)
 }else {
   $scope.redirect($scope.pages.otherpage)
 }
```

In the navigation controller if have a pages object:

```
$scope.pages = {
 ok : {pageName: 'ok', pageUrl: 'url'}
 otherpage: {pageName: 'nok', pageUrl: 'otherurl'}
```

the redirect in the navigation controller:

```
$scope.redirect = function (redirectobject){
   $scope.navigateToPage = redirectobject;
```

Then in the index:

ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-if="navigateToPage.pageName == page.pageName 
   ng-include="page.pageURL"

So this works fine. However now i would like to access the otherpage without calling the login function. So i would like to call the redirect function in the navigation controller with the otherpage object. However I can't seem to get this to work.

Test code:

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.get('url');
ptor.waitForAngular();
var page = {otherpage: {pageName: 'otherpage', pageURL: 'url'}};
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('classname')).evaluate('redirect(page)')
```

This code does find the element and does not generate any errors. However the redirect method is not called and the page is not set to otherpage in the browser.

Anybody have any ideas? I'm kinda lost. Is this the right approach or should I go in another direction?